Как добавить 5 ежедневных сеансов в таблицы, где таблицы связаны между собой отношением один ко многим?
Хочу убедиться, что я правильно решила задачу
Я написала запрос :
INSERT INTO calendar (doctor_id,client_id, visit_date)
VALUES
(7, 2, '2017-05-20 12:30:00'),
(7, 2, '2017-05-21 12:30:00'),
(7, 2, '2017-05-22 12:30:00'),
(7, 2, '2017-05-23 12:30:00'),
(7, 2, '2017-05-24 12:30:00')
Всё ок, он сработал. Но интересно, может можно было как то иным образом решить, более автоматизированно что ли. Или так и нужно каждую запись отдельно в Values самостоятельно писать?

